# Orbeon custom name for downloaded file

Tags: file, pdf, download, orbeon

I am using Orbeon's feature for generating PDFs and it works fine. But I need to use custom template for some of my forms as well. Since I already have code generating these custom template PDFs I would like to combine it with Orbeon's built in PDF feature.

Currently I have two buttons on my xforms - regular Orbeon PDF button (which genrates PDFs using Orbeon's built in functionality) and custom button, which sends xform data to my custom service generating PDFs using my template and gets back PDF file.

I have my button and service configured like this:

```
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.buttons.view.my_app.*">mypdf pdf</property>
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.resource.my_app.*.cs.buttons.mypdf" value="My PDF"/>

<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.process.mypdf.my_app.*">
        send(
        uri      = &quot;http://localhost:8080/myApp/getPdfXform&quot;,
        replace  = &quot;all&quot;,
        method   = &quot;post&quot;,
        content  = &quot;xml&quot;,
        annotate = &quot;id&quot;,
        nonrelevant = &quot;remove&quot;
    )
</property>
```

The problem I have is that mypdf button returns file called "view", which is my custom template PDF, but not with a name I generated in my service. In another words Orbeon replaces my custom filename with "view".

I tried to configure it using this property

```
<property as="xs:string"  name="oxf.fr.detail.pdf.filename.*.*" value="'testname'"/>
```

but it seems to apply only to PDFs generated by Orbeon, which makes sense.

My question is if there is a way to get file from my service with fileName I gave it?

Thank you.

Comment: Usually, a file name for a downloaded resource is provided to the browser using the `Content-Disposition` header. Try making your service return such a header. It should be forwarded to the browser by Orbeon Forms.

Comment: Thanks @ebruchez, if Content-Disposition and ContentType headers are set before the attachment is sent (rookie mistake) Orbeon handles it correctly.

Comment: Good to hear, thanks for confirming that.